# "isn't a function" error in flutter when trying to call a constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have a issue with calling a constructor

here LeftBar is constructor in lefr_bar.dart file

[image]

and i am calling it in home.dart file

[image]

but it is showing error as LeftBar isn't a function.
can some tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Do not post images of text

Comment: @Naveen Prajapati what does the error says?

Comment: @brook yonas it is showing error as "LeftBar isn't a function"

Comment: Please see In the second image at the bottom i am calling the LeftBar

Comment: have you tried closing or refreshing the IDE. I see you imported it correctly

Comment: Maybe it will be an error with the IDE. try closing and restart the IDE

Comment: thanks for the reply everyone, but the problem was i declared the same constructor in 2 different files

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've imported correctly.